# Formatting get lost when closing the document

Tags: libreoffice

I work in an `.odt`-document. Changes in formatting (like bold font) get not saved. When I open the document again, everything it set to *preformatted*. What have I done? How can I avoid that?

Here is the [link to the document](https://owncloud.tu-berlin.de/index.php/s/YHSFMiKw4VVUXNn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is currently just in plain text, and should not have been named with the `.odt` extension.

To fix this, go to File -> Save As.  In the `Save As Type` drop down list, select `ODF Text Document (.odt) (*.odt)`.  Then press Save.  When asked, press Yes to confirm overwriting the file.

Comment: Maybe I created the file via  -create new file -> textfile in context menu and inserted the extension manually. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Yes, that is probably what happened.